# Unable to submit my contact form with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to submit this form on my hosted domain, and I can figure why my php code is not working.
I have included the jquery and my script code in my html.php page corectly.
 I do not have any javascripts errors, still the form is not submited, can not figure that out.

**Php code**

```
    $name = filter_var($_POST['q1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['q2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $priority=filter_var($_POST['q3'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = filter_var($_POST['q4'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $buget = filter_var($_POST['q5'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);



    $sent = email($to,$email,$name,$buget,$message);
    if ($sent) {
        echo 'Message sent!';
    } else {
        echo 'Message couldn\'t sent!';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'All Fields are required';
}
return;
}

/**
* email function
*
* @return bool | void
**/
function email($to,$email,$name,$buget,$message){
  $header = array();
  $header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
  $header[] = "From: {$from_name}<{$from_mail}>";
  /* Set message content type HTML*/
  $header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
  $header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
  if( mail($to, $buget, $message, implode("\r\n", $header)) ) return true; 
}

?>
```

**Html form**

```
<html>
   <form id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" action="" method='post' autocomplete="off">
            <ol class="fs-fields">
                <li>
                    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">What's your name? </label>
                    <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q1" name="q1" type="text" placeholder="A name" required/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2" data-info="We won't send you spam, we promise...">What's your email address?</label>
                    <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q2" name="q2" type="email" placeholder="name@email.com" required/>
                </li>
                <li data-input-trigger>
                    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q3" data-info="This will help us know what kind of service you need">What's your priority for your new website?</label>
                    <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
                        <span><input id="q3b" name="q3" type="radio" value="conversion"/>     <label for="q3b" class="radio-conversion">Sell things</label></span>
                        <span><input id="q3c" name="q3" type="radio" value="social"/><label for="q3c" class="radio-social">Become famous</label></span>
                        <span><input id="q3a" name="q3" type="radio" value="mobile"/><label for="q3a" class="radio-mobile">Mobile market</label></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-input-trigger>
                    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" data-info="We'll make sure to use it all over">Choose a color for your website.</label>
                    <select class="cs-select cs-skin-boxes fs-anim-lower">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Pick a color</option>
                        <option value="#588c75" data-class="color-588c75">#588c75</option>
                        <option value="#b0c47f" data-class="color-b0c47f">#b0c47f</option>
                        <option value="#f3e395" data-class="color-f3e395">#f3e395</option>
                        <option value="#f3ae73" data-class="color-f3ae73">#f3ae73</option>
                        <option value="#da645a" data-class="color-da645a">#da645a</option>
                        <option value="#79a38f" data-class="color-79a38f">#79a38f</option>
                        <option value="#c1d099" data-class="color-c1d099">#c1d099</option>
                        <option value="#f5eaaa" data-class="color-f5eaaa">#f5eaaa</option>
                        <option value="#f5be8f" data-class="color-f5be8f">#f5be8f</option>
                        <option value="#e1837b" data-class="color-e1837b">#e1837b</option>
                        <option value="#9bbaab" data-class="color-9bbaab">#9bbaab</option>
                        <option value="#d1dcb2" data-class="color-d1dcb2">#d1dcb2</option>
                        <option value="#f9eec0" data-class="color-f9eec0">#f9eec0</option>
                        <option value="#f7cda9" data-class="color-f7cda9">#f7cda9</option>
                        <option value="#e8a19b" data-class="color-e8a19b">#e8a19b</option>
                        <option value="#bdd1c8" data-class="color-bdd1c8">#bdd1c8</option>
                        <option value="#e1e7cd" data-class="color-e1e7cd">#e1e7cd</option>
                        <option value="#faf4d4" data-class="color-faf4d4">#faf4d4</option>
                        <option value="#fbdfc9" data-class="color-fbdfc9">#fbdfc9</option>
                        <option value="#f1c1bd" data-class="color-f1c1bd">#f1c1bd</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q4">Describe how you imagine your new website</label>
                    <textarea class="fs-anim-lower" id="q4" name="q4" placeholder="Describe here"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q5">What's your budget?</label>
                    <input class="fs-mark fs-anim-lower" id="q5" name="q5" type="number" placeholder="1000" step="100" min="100"/>
                </li>
            </ol><!-- /fs-fields -->
            <button class="fs-submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
        </form><!-- /fs-form -->
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $('#form'); // contact form
var submit = $('#submit');  // submit button


// form submit event
form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
    // sending ajax request through jQuery
    $.ajax({
        url: '', // form action url
        type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
        dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
        data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
        beforeSend: function() {

            submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
        },
        success: function(data) {

            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
            submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: For one your javascript is looking for #form while the id of your form is myform. Your submit button has no id even though you are calling it like it does. My bet is that your submit event is not even firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first your form Id is `myform` and to submit the form using ajax you can simply get a button and on click of it you can use ajax like this:

**html**

```
<button class="fs-submit" id="submit">Send answers</button>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $('#myform'); // contact form id
// form submit event
 $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
   //your ajax call here
});
});
```

Comment: yes, I was tired last night, and didn`t have the power to see those to, I was to much concentrating on my php code, ty, me idiot

Answer (score 1):

Give submit button id

```
<input type="submit" class="fs-submit" type="submit" id="form-submit">Send answers</button>
```

In Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('$form-submit').click(function(){
    //your ajax code with form field value
   });
});
```